# Xcode Unable To Open The Project After Update

Tags: xcode

Xcode can not detect workspace file.

I also tried "open another project" to open my latest project.

Xcode says in both ways : The Document "xxx.wcworkspace" could not be opened. The file doesn't exist.

The file exists.

Xcode version : 10.2.1 (10E1001)

Comment: delete workspace, reinstall your pods

Comment: after restarting my mac it worked. 2 hours of debugging omg.